# Comparar dois arrays de objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, email, mongodb, comparação

Preciso fazer a comparação de 2 arrays em Javascript, um que retorna de uma consulta do MongoDB e o outro vem do provedor de emails.

Os dois critérios de comparação são a ID do email e a caixa à qual ele pertence, e o email será descartado se OS DOIS critérios coincidirem, senão o email será gravado no banco.

Até aí tudo ok, o problema é que eu não sei a lógica nem os métodos para fazer isso de forma correta, já tentei usando 2 `for` e nenhum deu certo.

Servidor:

```
let dados = [];
    for (let l = 0; l < array.length; l++) { //array é o vetor com os emails que vem do provedor
        dados.push({
            idEmail: array[l].id,
            remetente: array[l].remetente,
            destinatario: array[l].destinatario,
            assunto: array[l].assunto,
            texto: array[l].texto,
            box: flag
        });
    }
    let pesquisa = {'idEmail': {$ne: dados.idEmail}, 'box': {$ne: dados.box}};
    db.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
        mongoclient.collection('emails', function (err, collection) {
            collection.find(pesquisa).toArray(function (err, results) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    mongoclient.close()
                } else {
                let comp = [];
                for (let a = 0; a < results.length; a++) {
                    comp.push({
                        id: results[a].idEmail,
                        caixa: results[a].box
                    });
                }
                for (let l = 0; l < comp.length; l++) {
                    if (comp[l].idEmail === dados[l].idEmail && comp[l].caixa === dados.box) {
                        console.log('Repetido')
                    } else if (comp[l].idEmail !== dados[l].idEmail && comp[l].caixa !== dados.box) {
                        mongoclient.collection('emails', function (err, collection) {
                            collection.insert(dados, function (err, records) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err)
                                } else {
                                    console.log(records)
                                }
                                mongoclient.close()
                            })
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em

```
comp.push({
   id: results[a].idEmail,
   caixa: results[a].box
});
```

Sua `key` é referenciada como `id` e na condição é tratada como valor

o certo seria

```
    if (comp[l].id === dados[l].idEmail && comp[l].caixa === dados.box) {
                            console.log('Repetido')
                        } else {
                        mongoclient.collection('emails', function (err, collection) {
                        collection.insert(dados, function (err, records) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err)
                            } else {
                                console.log(records)
                            }
                            mongoclient.close()
                        })
                    })
    }
```

repare também que seu `else if` contrária seu `if` tornando-o simplesmente falso, basta substituí-lo por `else`.

Comment: Ok, vou testar aqui e já retorno com o resultado.

E só uma dúvida, é só retirar o `if` que funciona??

Comment: retire o else if e deixe só else e substitua seu if pelo if acima, editei para ficar mais fácil

Comment: Implementei esse código que vc editou, porém não está gravando no banco de dados...

Comment: E agora descobri que o código nem está sendo executado, ele para antes de chegar nessas funções...

Comment: sempre bom ficar de olho no console, e ir debugando os valores com 'console.log' , caso os arrays que queira comparar sejam associativos o código acima já basta se quer comparar cada valor com um array inteiro, 2 loopings são necessários ou outra função exemplo array_map que faz isso mt bem

Comment: É o que eu vou fazer, muito obrigado pela ajuda @Felipe Duarte